# How to get Vim to correctly display file instead of showing ^@ characters

Tags: windows, vim, notepad

I have a file which shows different things in Notepad and Vim.

The file displays normally under Windows Notepad:

[image: picture of file in Windows Notepad]

Strange character are added to each character when using Vim.

[image: picture of file in Vim]

Anyone know how to dismiss those strange character in Vim under Windows environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see: `TSS` is displayed as `T^@S^@S^@`(binary: `54 00 53 00 53 00`).
Because vim shows `\0x00` as `^@`. It sounds like `UTF16LE`.

---

You can convert `UTF16LE` to `UTF8`:

```
:e ++enc=UTF16LE
:set fenc=UTF8
:w
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like unicode.  You can open the file in notepad and save it as ascii.

Alternatively, if you don't want to create a new file, you can change your vimrc settings to enable multi-byte character encoding.

Here's more information from the vim wiki:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode

Answer (score 1):

The file is stored as UTF-16, where each character is represented by two bytes. VIM opens it as if it was an ASCII or UTF-8 file, so each pair of bytes is turned into two characters.

Notepad recognises the encoding, but apparently VIM doesn't. Specify the encoding when you open the file.

Comment: Guffa: How can i do that in VIM? any ref link? hopia's solution not work :(

Comment: Have you read the info on the page he is linking to? What did you try?

Comment: @KitHo: That solution doesn't work because it uses UTF-8, not UTF-16. You could try the same with UTF-16le or UTF-16be. You can find some other possible solutions by searching http://www.google.se/search?q=vim+utf-16